# I have two rdd how to put in one (spark, scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have two rdd. The first has x coordinates ( one column) and the second has the y coordinates (one column) . 
 I want the result to be one rdd with one column with the format (x,y) . Is there any solution?

For example: 
first rdd has: 1,2,3
second rdd has: 4,5,6
The result: (1,4),(2,5),(3,6)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to combine two RDDs is by using zip, so you could do something like

```
val coordinates = x.zip(y)
```

However, the order of the elements is not guaranteed as in Spark you have your elements split into partitions. You should have a way of performing a join by having a key that identifies each record

Comment: I understand the consequences :D . Thank you very much, it works!

Comment: You are welcome